# Given a table of values $x$, $y$ and $z$, find a formula that expresses $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, parametric

I'm not really versed in this kind of mathematics, but I ran into this problem while programming, so I find myself turning to the hivemind. (Thus I don't even know the proper tags to use here... Feel free to correct them, whoever can..)

Given a table of values for $x$, $y$ and $z$, how would I go about finding a formula for $z$ that expresses $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$?

Also, there is a chance that the values I have for $z$ in the table, are not exact (they may be close to $99\%$ accurate). Is there a way to account for some level of tolerance?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) help?

Comment: What have I gotten myself into...
I appreciate your help, Gary, I'm gonna have to spend some time learning how to read and interpret all this.
In the meantime, I have found, due to the nature of my problem, that even this would not give me the results I am looking for.
I have missed a major part of the math, and thus my thinking has ignored some important factors. I have to rethink some things, and then approach this from another angle.
Thank you though, good sir!